# How to dynamic add/remove handlers outside of a handler

Tags: netty, nio

I've got such a use case:

1. There are some predefined pipelines, e.g. `pipeline1 = handlerA <-> handlerB <-> handlerC`, `pipeline2 = handlerA <-> handlerC` and so on
2. The user can choose one of these pipelines, and then send message to the netty server that should be handled by the chosen pipeline.

I know netty supported dynamically adding/removing handlers in pipeline, but however I could find almost all the samples said how to implement the function just inside a handler. For my case, the pipeline is changed by user who is outside of the handlers but message which is inside of the handlers.

A very straight solution is to shutdown the current running netty server and then launch a new netty server with other pipeline when call `childHandler` method.

May I know whether there are  better solutions or not? The shutdown and launch are really expensive operation.

Comment: Maybe having a special trigger within one of the top handlers to managed this?  

When the user wants to change, it will send a user event trigger and this handler (extending ChannelInboundHandler or one of its descendents) will be notified by `userEventTriggered` which then gives you access to ctx.  

The Javadoc method `void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception Gets called if an user event was triggered.`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Would your please explain how to send a user event trigger outside the pipeline more deeply? As I know, for calling `fireUserEventTriggered` method, I still need a `ChannelPipeline` or `ChannelHandlerContext` instance. However, if I can get either one outside, I can then add or remove handlers in it...

Comment: Damn! Yes, you're right! What I can think of is to add at first (except if TLS at first, then second), is to add a specific decoder on your own that will accept 2 kinds of messages:
1) standard messages which will pass through the next handler in the pipeline  2) Special notice from user messages which will change the pipeline and not continue with the pipeline, returning immediately.

Comment: Yes, it's also one of the solutions I've thought, which is to create a netty client in the service and send special message/event to the server in order to replace handlers in pipeline just according to the meesage/event. But eventually, I still want to know whether there are some architectural mechanisms in netty to implement it. If negative, I have to use these non-architectural solutions.

Comment: You have to access to the pipeline.
Maybe you can store the pipeline in a outside object that is shared with the user? Then in the constructor of the initializer, you passed this object and set the pipeline to this object. Then you can act directly outside Netty context.

Comment: I'm afraid a `pipeline` is instantiated just after a client connects or transfers data to the `ServerSockerChannel`. It is just defined in the `initChannel` method of `ChannelInitializer` class that the pipeline is assembled by which handlers and also their order in it. At the point of the definition, there should be no instances of `Pipeline` or `ChannelHandlerContext`. What I want to know is whether I can change the definition of the pipeline for a `ServerSockerChannel`. It might be similar to the `attach` method of `SelectionKey` class in Java NIO model.

Answer (score 0):

The `ChannelPipeline` can be shared and modified from any Thread. If you need to be able to access the pipeline before you connect you can just call `bootstrap.register()` which will register the channel to the evenloop only (without connect). Then you can obtain the reference and one you have it just call `connect()`

Comment: May I confirm that you mean I can get the `ChannelPipeline` via `ServerBootstrap.register().channel().pipeline()`? I tried the method just after calling `ServerBootstrap.childHandler(...)` and before `ServerBootstrap.bind().sync()`, but it seems the new handler not being added to the pipeline.